# Integrability of characteristic function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a following questions that I am having trouble.

Let $E = \{(\frac{a}{b}, \frac{c}{b}) : a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}, a \text{ and } b \text{ are relatively prime}\}.$

1. For what $a \in [1,2]$ is the function $f_a(y) = \chi_E(a,y)$ integrable on $[1,2]$?
2. For what $b \in [1,2]$ is the function $f_b(x) = \chi_E(x,b)$ integrable on $[1,2]$?
3. Is the function $\chi_E$ integrable on $[1,2] \times [1,2]$?
4. What does the Fubini's theorem have to say about the function $\chi_E$?

In my textbook, the characteristic function $\chi_S(x,y)$ is equal to 1 if $(x,y) \in S \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ otherwise 0.

First, I don't think I understood the notation. The set $E$ is set of pairs of fractions such that $a$ and $b$ are relatively primes. But the first and second question, we are considering $a$ and $b$ in the interval $[1,2]$. Since it talks about the function $f_a(y)$ and $f_b(x)$ on $[1,2],$ $y$ and $x$ should be real numbers I think. Then, can I say $\chi_E(a,y) = 0$ and $\chi_E(x,b) = 0$ if $y$ and $x$ are not integers?? Then, how can I show that those functions are integrable??

Comment: What "kind" of integral are you speaking of? Riemann, Lebesgue or others?

Comment: @Davide F We are dealing with Riemann integral.

Comment: Ah, of course you do. It would have been too easy otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\pi_k E = \{ x_k  \}_{x \in E}$.

1. We have $f_x(y) = 1_E(x,y)$. If $x \notin \pi_1 E$, then $f_x = 0$. If $x \in \pi_1 E$, then $x = {a \over b}$ where $a,b$ are coprime integers. It should be clear that there are only finitely many integers $p$ such that ${p \over b} \in [1,2]$, hence $f_x$ is zero except for finitely many points. It follows that $f_x$ is integrable.
2. We have $g_y(x) = 1_E(x,y)$. If $y$ is irrational, then $g_y = 0$, which is integrable. If $y$
   is rational, there are infinitely many pairs $(c_n,b_n)$ such that ${c_n \over b_n} = y$. Let $F_y = \{ x \in [1,2] | (x,y)  \in E \}$. It is straightforward to see that $F_y$ is a countable set that is dense in $[1,2]$. It follows that $g_y$ is not integrable.
3. Let $R \subset [1,2]^2$ be a non trivial rectangle. It is clear from the preceding remarks that $1_E$ takes on the values $\{0,1\}$ in the rectangle, hence $1_E$ is not integrable on $[1,2]^2$.
4. I'm not sure what is being asked here.